# Slow performance compared to Ubuntu Live - USB 3 drive

Tags: boot, 16.04, usb-drive, performance

I have created an installation USB (Sandisk Cruzer, USB 2.0) and its performance is fairly good - firefox and all other applications run pretty smoothly. 
I wanted a portable setup, so I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a PNY 64 GB USB 3.0 drive. 
I have an 500mb Fat32 partition for EFI, an 11 GB swap partition, and the rest as an ext4 partition.

I had some initial booting problems (graphics) which seems to be miraculously resolved by some restarts. However, performance is extremely slow. By that I mean that the Live Ubuntu of the Sandisk USB 2.0 drive loads is ~10 seconds, while the full installation from the PNY USB 3.0 pendrive loads at ~10 minutes. And it is extremely laggy.

Any idea what should I do?

Comment: This seems to be a problem with the graphics driver. You can try with the boot option nomodeset. If you install a proprietary driver, it might work well in this particular computer, but it will be less portable to computers with other graphics hardware.  An alternative for good portability is a persistent live drive, which you can make with mkusb. Please tell us about your graphics chip/card (brand name and model), and we can give you better advice.

Comment: I do not know much about Radeon cards, but I think that the new ones should work rather well with new versions of Ubuntu. It might be worthwhile to try with the boot option nomodeset, but you might not find a suitable proprietary driver. Let us wait for someone who has own experience of this card or a similar Radeon card.

Comment: Thanks once again, how do boot with nomodeset options? I'm new to ubuntu. As for my needs, I needed the ubuntu setup for programming IDE (python, deep neural networks etc.), but I was concerned that as persistent setup has only 4gb, it will not be sufficient.

Comment: I will make an 'answer' with links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use this link and links from it to use boot options and in this case try **nomodeset**,

   [Boot options](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808)
2. A persistent live setup is limited to 4 GB if you use a 'casper-rw' ***file***, but you can ***use a partition with the label 'casper-rw', and then you are only limited by the size of the USB drive***. You can even use an SSD or hard disk drive for it, but there are USB 3 pendrives, that are fast and big enough. You can use mkusb to create persistent live systems automatically with a 'casper-rw' partition. See the following links and and links from them.

   [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

   [Speed and size of USB drives](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Prerequisites)
3. But the best solution would be to make the installed system work well. Let us hope someone will chip in and help you with the AMD Radeon R270 card.

Comment: Thanks! The problem was that the PNY performance was really poor.  This really helped me with installation on a different drive.

Comment: I'm glad that you solved the problem :-)